# How can I sort one set of data to match another set of data in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data that is not in alphabetical or numerical order.  I want to sort a second list of the same date to match the first list.  I cannot change the order of the data.  My goal is to paste additional data from the second set back into the first data set.

```
**DATA SET A**           **DATA SET B**
22350   ____              BH160   100
22355   ____              22350   125
BH160   ____              BH190   200 
BH190   ____              22355   150
```

I would like to get the numerical value from column 2 of DATA SET B to show up in a new column of DATA SET A.  For example, I want 125 to show up in line 1, column 2 of DATA SET 1.

My list contains about 200 unique numbers and I need to update it every week.

Can someone help me?  Maybe with a macro that I could use each week?

Answer (score 10):

You could also use `INDEX MATCH`, which is more "powerful" than vlookup. This would give you exactly what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: It'd be helpful in your answer to explain why and how INDEX MATCH is more powerful than VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `VLOOKUP`.

Assuming those are in columns A and B in Sheet1 and Sheet2 each, 22350 is in cell A2 of Sheet1, you can use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)
```

This will return you `#N/A` if there are no matches. Drag/Fill/Copy&Paste the formula to the bottom of your table and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply link both cells, and have an **=Cell** formula in each column like, `=Sheet2!A2` in Sheet 1 A2 and `=Sheet2!B2` in Sheet 1 B2, and drag it down, and then **sort** those two columns the way you want.

- If they don't sort the way you want, put the order you want to sort them in another column and sort all three columns by that.
- If you drag it down further and get zeros you can edit the =Cell formula to show "" **IF** there is nothing. =(if(cell="","",cell)
- Cutting, pasting, deleting, and inserting rows is something to be weary of. **#REF!** errors could occur.

This would be better if your unique items change also, then all you would do is sort and be done.